# Unable to style top level Category in magento

Tags: css, categories

On this page: http://www.dancetimepublications.com/index.php/our-dance-dvd-store/production-style/dance-in-film.html I am unable to style just the top level categories (Dance by Era, Dance Interests, Production Styles, etc.).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the top-level categories in the layered navigation? Appearantly, all the links have identifiable css-classes assigned, such as "nav-2-1-1", "nav-2-1-1" etc... You can apply the css for any of these links in your stylesheets such as:

```
.nav-2-1-1
{
   color: green;
}
```